# Is the CSR (PKCS#10) the same for CV Certificate and X.509?

Tags: x509, csr, pkcs#10

Is the CSR Certificate Signing Request (PKCS#10) the same for Card Verifiable Certificates CVC and X.509?

Best regards.

Comment: As the most common format for CSR is the PKCS #10 (used for X.509), it seems that CVC certificate request is different; Does anyone used a specific CVC API to create a CVC request as it is the case for X.509 certificate using Bouncy Castle.